# Map if it can be converted

Tags: python, algorithm, list, casting

I have the following list:

```
a = ['1', '2', 'hello']
```

And I want to obtain

```
a = [1, 2, 'hello']
```

I mean, convert all integers I can.

This is my function:

```
def listToInt(l):
    casted = []
    for e in l:
        try:
            casted.append(int(e))
        except:
            casted.append(e)
    return casted
```

But, can I use the `map()` function or something similar?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have? Looks fine to me. It's readable, EAFP. Nothing wrong with it.

Comment: You can use `try/except` in the function that you call with `map`.

Comment: @idjaw I think it is correct, but I want to know if I can do it as Barmar suggest

Comment: Looks OK to me too. Just a small improvement: `except (ValueError, TypeError):`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure you can do this with `map`

```
def func(i):
    try:
        i = int(i)
    except:
        pass
    return i
a = ['1', '2', 'hello']
print(list(map(func, a)))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
a = ['1', '2', 'hello']
y = [int(x) if x.isdigit() else x for x in a]
>> [1, 2, 'hello']
>> #tested in Python 3.5
```

Maybe something like this?